# Delete row from table ( Cannot read property 'data' of null)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-props, react-state-management

I am new to Gatsbyjs and reactjs and i still don't understand much of how props.and states work.

I am building this simple application that gets a list of customers from an API and a list of tasks for each customer.

I am using Reach/Router to render the components. Everything works as expected as for as to displaying a table with a list of customers and when i click on a customer a new page is rendered which shows a list of task for that said customer.

Now, i am trying to make the table editable. I am starting by trying to simply delete some rows. this is where I am stuck.

## edit

I believe that i get the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null` because i am trying to access data (state) which is managed by the `fetch.js` class. How can I pass the data (state) to the ClientTasks class?

## ---

I have the following code

> index.js

```
import React from "react"
import { createHistory, LocationProvider } from '@reach/router'
import createHashSource from '../utils/hash-source'
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';

import "../css/main.css"
import "../css/materialize.css"
import "../css/blackjack.css"
import '../../node_modules/react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';


import { NavBar } from '../components/navBar'
import { Main } from '../components/main'

const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window;

let source 
let history 
if (typeof window !== `undefined` ) {
  source = createHashSource()
  history = createHistory(source)
}

class App extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <LocationProvider history={history}>
        <div className="app" >
          <NavBar/>
          <Main/>
          <ToastContainer position="bottom-right"/>
        </div>
      </LocationProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

> main.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router } from "@reach/router"

import { Home } from '../components/home'
import { Customers } from './customers';
import { ClientTasks } from './clientTasks1';


const Main = () => (
  <main className="main container">
      <Router className="row">
        <Home path='/'/>
        <Customers path='customers'/>
        <ClientTasks path="customers/tasks/:customerId"/>
      </Router>
  </main>
)

export { Main }
```

> fetch.js
>
> I am using this file to work as a single class component that helps me fetch data for the tables I am displaying (customers and tasks). It works fine as is. there is probably better ways to do it, but for now this is how i am doing it. Any pointers are welcome.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const axios = require('axios')
class Fetch extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        data: null,
        isLoading: true,
        error: null,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true });

      axios.get(this.props.url)
        .then(result => this.setState({
          data: result.data,
          isLoading: false
        }))
        .catch(error => this.setState({
          error,
          isLoading: false
        }));
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.children(this.state);
    }
  }


export default Fetch
```

> Customers.js
>
> This where i display my customers' table. I have links on each customer and with the help of "reach/router" render the cutomer tasks table.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from "@reach/router"

import Fetch from './fetch'
import { UploadForm } from './upLoadtoS3'
import { AnimatedDiv } from './AnimatedDiv'

const APIURL = `https://SomeAIPURL`
let APIQuery = `customers`

const Customers = () => (
  <Fetch url={APIURL + APIQuery}>
    {({ data, isLoading, error }) => {
      if (!data) {
        return (
          <div className="progress">
            <div className="indeterminate"></div>
          </div>)
      }
      if (error) {
        return <p>{error.message}</p>;
      }
      if (isLoading) {
        return (
          <div className="progress">
            <div className="indeterminate"></div>
          </div>)
      }
      return (
        <AnimatedDiv className='col m12 s12'>
          <h1> Client List </h1>
          <table className='highlight'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Client ID</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((customer, i) => (
                <tr key={customer.customerid}>
                  <td>{i + 1}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Link to={`tasks/${customer.customerid}`}>{customer.customerid}</Link>
                  </td>
                  <td>{customer.enabled}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <UploadForm></UploadForm>
        </AnimatedDiv>
      );
    }
    }
  </Fetch>
)
export { Customers }
```

> ClientTasks.js
>
> Fetch is called once again and populates the table with data pulled from the API.
>   I used another file to define the contents of this table. `listTasks.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from "@reach/router"

import Fetch from './fetch'
// import Delete from './delete'
import { AnimatedDiv } from './AnimatedDiv'
import DisplayList from './listTasks'

const APIURL = `https://SomeAIPURL`
const CUSTOMERQUERY = `tasks?customerid=`
const TASKQUERY = `&taskid=`



class ClientTasks extends React.Component {

  handleDelete(taskToBeDeleted) {
    // console.log(taskToBeDeleted);
    let newData = this.state.data.filter((_data) => {
      return _data != taskToBeDeleted
    });
    this.setState({ data: newData })
    }

  render() {
    let customerId = this.props.customerId
    return (
      <Fetch url={APIURL + CUSTOMERQUERY + customerId}>
        {({ data, isLoading, error }) => {
          if (!data) {
            return (
              <div className="progress">
                <div className="indeterminate"></div>
              </div>)
          }
          if (error) {
            return <p>{error.message}</p>;
          }
          if (isLoading) {
            return (
              <div className="progress">
                <div className="indeterminate"></div>
              </div>)
          }
          else {
          return (
            <AnimatedDiv className='col m12 s12'>
              <h1>{customerId} Tasks</h1>
              <table id="customerList" className="highlight" >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Task ID</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Asset Category</th>
                    <th>Asset</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

              <DisplayList handleDelete={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} data={data}/>

              </table>
              <Link to='/customers'> Back to Client List ... </Link>
            </AnimatedDiv>

          )
          }
        }
        }
      </Fetch>
    )
  }
}

export { ClientTasks }
```

>

> Here i have an `onClick` function that runs `handleDelete` inside the `ClientTasks.js` file.
>
> If i `console.log(taskstobedeleted)` then the console shows me the contents of the row that i am trying to delte.  This is as for as i get.  Then i am trying to use the following function in `clientasks.js` but i get an error in the console the says `Cannot read property 'data' of null)` and i believe that is because the props of data are the accessible that this `clientTasks` class.

I am still learning and there are better ways to structure the code, but i have hit a wall and i don't want to rebuild the app from scratch, if i did i would probably use redux, but that is another lesson for later. I figured that this project of mine is small enough and does not need Redux yet.

**Can somehow give me any pointers of how to delete the rows of my table?**

```
  handleDelete(taskToBeDeleted) {
    // console.log(taskToBeDeleted);
    let newData = this.state.data.filter((_data) => {
      return _data != taskToBeDeleted
    });
    this.setState({ data: newData })
    }
```

> Listtasks.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Icon } from 'react-icons-kit'
import { ic_delete_forever } from 'react-icons-kit/md/ic_delete_forever'

export default class DisplayList extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <tbody>
                {this.props.data.map((task) => (
                    <tr key={task.taskid}>
                        <td>{task.taskid}</td>
                        <td>{task.qty}</td>
                        <td>{task.category}</td>
                        <td>{task.asset}</td>
                        <td>{task.location}</td>
                        <td>{task.enabled}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button style={{ padding: '0px', background: 'transparent', border: '0', cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={this.props.handleDelete.bind(this, task)} >
                                <Icon style={{ color: 'red' }} icon={ic_delete_forever} />
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your function should be like this:

```
  handleDelete(taskToBeDeleted) {
    // console.log(taskToBeDeleted);
    let newData = this.state.data.filter((_data) => _data.taskid != taskToBeDeleted.taskid});
    this.setState({ data: newData })
    }
```

If your console is giving you object that you wanted, then, first, you do not need return in arrow function since return is implicit. Second, all of your tasks have been returned because you were asking for two objects are they the same which will always be false even if they have the same key value pairs inside of them. They have different references. That is why I used id since I suppose the value of that key is number and you can evaluate that with operator == or !=

Comment: that did not help, i believe that i get the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null` because i am trying to access data (state) which is managed by the `fetch.js` class. How can I pass the data (state) to the ClientTasks class?